# How to prove that $\dim_k(k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]/\sqrt{I})=|V(I)|$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. How to prove that $\dim_k(k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]/\sqrt{I})=|V(I)|$?

I know that Hilbert Nullstellensatz will be required, but I can't figure out how.

With the notation common in algebraic geometry, the Nullstellensatz can also be formulated as ${\displaystyle {\hbox{I}}({\hbox{V}}(I))={\sqrt {I}}}$ where $ {\displaystyle I\subset k[X_{1},\ldots ,X_{n}]} $ ideal.

Comment: Hint: consider the exact sequence of $k$-vector spaces $0\to m_x \to R \to k\to 0$ where $m_x$ is the maximal ideal associated to the $k$-point $x$.

Comment: For a simple counterexample when $k$ is not algebraically closed consider $k=\mathbb R$ and $I=(x^2+1)$.

Comment: In order to prove it when $k$ is algebraically closed assume that $I$ is radical. Then $I$ is a finite intersection of maximal ideals, and use CRT.